# pytesseract image to string read order

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

I'm having a problem with image_to_string with pytesseract. I am currently taking screenshots of a video feed through cv2.VideoCapture() at 3fps. The videos I'm working with are over an hour long so im generating over 10000 images. My images are writing using cv2.imwrite() in order of when they occur but when I am trying to read the screenshots they are reading in random order. So far my code looks like this for the image_to_string:

```
def get_Text():
for i in os.listdir(image):
    print(str(i))
    imageRead = Image.open(image + '/' + i)
    # Writing the image to a string for storage
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imageRead, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
    print(text)
```

Heres and example of the output:

```
frame23320.png
[LON] Zer0 — [TX] Scump
frame71300.png
[TX] Shotzzy - [LDN] Nastie
frame27620.png
[TX] Dashy — [LDN] Afro
```

Edit: Ended up using natsort. Thanks to furas for the suggestion.

Comment: system doesn't have to list names in expected order. Use `sorted()` - `for i in sorted(os.listdir(image)):`

Comment: [natural sorting](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/)